# How to display single tweet with descendants and parents with javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm trying to visualize a single tweet on my website with its parents and descendants. Here is the code I'm using:

HTML:

```
<div id="tweet_container"></div>
```

JS:

```
twttr.widgets.createTweet(
  statusId,
  document.getElementById("tweet_container"),
  {
    linkColor: "#55acee"
  }
);
```

There is a field "conversation" but the only option I see is "none" - if set the parent tweet is hidden. Is there an option to display a tweet the way it's displayed on twitter after it's clicked (descendants are shown as well)?

Comment: I don't know twitter API, but if you had actually provided some test case, I would sure help you figure it out. You shouldn't rely on everyone knowing the API when posting API related questions.

Comment: My use case is simple: I need to visualize on my web page a single tweet by ID, with it's parents and descendants. I need it to look like twitter when you click on "view conversation" - the tweet is on white background and above it and below it you see the next / previous tweets on the thread in a bit darker background. I don't care about styling, just need to present the tweets.

Comment: Still, you gave me (and others who answer question), nothing to work with. I can't help you.